# Fatal error for /etc/cron.daily/cyrus-imapd

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I have CentOS 7 VPS on Digital Ocean, and after I started crontab I am getting this email everyday.

```
/etc/cron.daily/cyrus-imapd:

fatal error: invalid value 'MyDomain.com' for virtdomains in line 1
```

Can anyone please let me know why is this happening, and what is the solution to this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the configuration for `/etc/imapd.conf`

Apparently you have a mis-configured domain, e.g. `MyDomain.com`.
Detailed info on `imapd` configuration can be found [here](https://cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.2.13p1/man/imapd.conf.5.php)